# Using Fullcalendar with Twitter Bootstrap in Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm very much a novice in the Ruby on Rails world. As a small exercise, I'm attempting to set up a basic (but polished) calendar with tagging capabilities. Fullcalendar is working very nicely for the calendar and acts-as-taggable-on is a nice tagging system.

Where I'm running into trouble, however, is with using Twitter Bootstrap for nice buttons and layouts. I can't seem to get the gem to actually do anything; my pages look completely unchanged after installing it following Railscast #328 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics).

Right now, my application.html.erb looks like this:

```
  1 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
  2 <head>
  3   <title>Calendar</title>
  4   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "fullcalendar.css" %>
  5   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-fullcalender.css" %>
  6   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" %>
  7   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.js" %>
  8   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.rest.js" %>
  9   <%= javascript_include_tag "rails.js" %>
 10   <%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>
 11 
 12   <!-- these are needed for the calendar. -->
 13   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" %>
 14   <%= javascript_include_tag "fullcalendar.js" %>
 15   <%= javascript_include_tag "calendar.js" %>
 16 
 17   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
 18 
 19   <%= javascript_tag "var AUTH_TOKEN = #{form_authenticity_token.inspect};" if protect_against_forgery? %>
 20 
 21 </head>
 22 <body>
 23 
 24 <%= yield %>
 25 
 26 </body>
 27 </html>
```

The bootstrap-fullcalendar.css file was shamelessly "borrowed" from brennovich's solution at https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap/issues/37. I placed the file in both /app/assets/stylesheets and /public/stylesheets but have had no luck with it.

Any suggestions as to how to get this working and/or an alternative to Bootstrap for nice formatting?

EDIT:

Gemfile, application.css, and application.js are posted in one of the comments below (I only have a limited number of links, sadly :-/)

Also noticed that I get an "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/bootstrap-fullcalender.css"):" error while starting the server...that seems important.

Comment: I imagine you already ran bundle and restarted the server as well :). Please, put the content of your Gemfile, and the content of both your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: I did run bundle and restart the server. Thanks for checking :)  
Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/6mVdz3Qq  
application.css: http://pastebin.com/7ud8UY1B (it seems to just be a load of comments?)  
application.js: http://pastebin.com/TdkY5JdT  


One thing that I did not notice before is that I get an "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/bootstrap-fullcalender.css"):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since someone upvoted this I decided to look back on what I did to fix this, since I did get this resolved eventually. It appears all I did was change the line in my gemfile to install from latest build, as per the instructions on the gem's github page:

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

After that, it basically worked right out of the box. I was also able to later add on a bootstrap datetimepicker and colorpicker without much difficulty. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you are sure the file is on app/assets/bootstrap-fullcalender.css, then you don't need it on /public/stylesheets, remove it from /public/stylesheets (its gonna be precompile by rails so not worries about that).

Then restart your server, and this url should give you the stylesheet:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap-fullcalender.css
```

Check that and we can continue from there

Comment: I'll remember that about /public. And going to `http://localhost:3000/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-fullcalender.css` returns a 'No route matches [GET] "/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-fullcalender.css" ' error despite bootstrap-fullcalendar.css being in the specified location...do I need to add anything to routes.rb?

Comment: No, any css file that you throw on /assets/stylesheets, then it will appear when you request your_lost/assets/name_of_stylesheet.css. It may be that some times you need to restart your server, but that's all. I mean, you are in a "development" environment, right? You can try to change the name of the file to see if it helps, but you don't need to do anything else. Later, depending on your configuration, you should update the assets compilation settings on config/environments/production.rb, but that's for production environment.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; it's been a busy week. The URL still did not work this project, but worked in a different test project...I must have unknowingly changed some sort of setting. Will investigate this evening.

Comment: Yeah, even though RAILS_ENV is set to "development" I can't view _any_ stylesheets this way. Any thoughts? This seems very odd...

Comment: Not really, if the file is there you should be able to get the file from the requests, if you are not being able to get it, then its something rare which is not the expected behavior with rails.

Comment: Bringing this back from the dead a bit. Found that the asset pipeline was disabled, but enabling it seriously messed up the app. Also found that placing stylesheets in /public/stylesheets and using the path localhost:3000/stylesheets/boostrap-fullcalendar.css displayed it properly. I'm not 100% sure what this means in regards to the project as a whole...